# best way to change download link based on an input field?

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, download

I program in C (embedded programming) but have no experience for web-based stuff. I have a need to download a different link based on an input field.

- input serial number in field.
- click download link
- if serial number = a,b,c etc.. download file_version_a
- else if serial number = e,f,g, etc.. download file_version_b

what is the best script language to use to for something like this? I've searched all over and haven't found much that seems relevant and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below in your html page :

```
<input type="text" id="serialnumbers" name="serialnumbers"></input>
<input type="button" id="download" name="download" onclick="downloadlink();return false;"value="Download Now"></input>

<script>

function downloadlink(){
var serialnos=document.getElementById('serialnumbers').value;
serialnos = serialnos.trim();
if( serialnos == "a" ||  serialnos == "b" || serialnos == "c" )
window.location = download file_version_a;
}
else if( serialnos == "e" ||  serialnos == "f" || serialnos == "g" )
window.location = download file_version_b;
}
</script>
```

Also,some suggestions for the same would be to check Jquery,very convenient Javascript library ,Refer Doc :https://jquery.com/